# Google : contact search [Method: people.searchDirectoryPeople ]

Tags: google-people-api

I'm using google directory search API but i coudn't retrive the users names(firstName, lastName) details in response even after applying proper readMask
below is the request details:

```
{
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer access_token",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "uri": "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:searchDirectoryPeople?query=ajay&readMask=names,nicknames,addresses,calendarUrls,emailAddresses,organizations,phoneNumbers,photos,relations&sources=DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_CONTACT&sources=DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE"
}
```

**NOTE:** I'm getting the proper results with api, but issue is for some contact results, i'm not getting names(firstname, lastname) data/info in the response

Comment: What are you getting instead? Any error? Please consider replacing the commas with `%2C`.

Comment: I saw your edit now. In this case, are you sure you have added that information (`firstName`, `lastName`) to the contacts for which you are not receiving that data?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a `"PERMISSION_DENIED"` error, this means the access token you are using doesn't have the directory access scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.readonly
```

Which is required for accessing directory contacts.

Also your sources param should be: 
`sources=DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_CONTACT,DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE`

and not
`sources=DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_CONTACT&sources=DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE`

*P.S.
It's a very bad idea to post real access-tokens in public posts, you should always redact secrets when you post your API requests online.*

Comment: I'm getting the results with api but issue is for some contact results not getting names(firstname, lastname) data in the response

Comment: that's a dummy token which is random just for the purpose of understanding i have added

Comment: You are getting email id of all but first & last name of some. The domain admin might not include your full details. Cross-check on UI for directory users list details on UI with admin permission.